# Why is my IDE telling me my if statement is redundant?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

Why is NetBeans with TMC (IDE recommended by MOOC fi Java) telling my that my final if statement is redundant?

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        if (object == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        LicensePlate compared = (LicensePlate) object;
        
        if (!this.country.equals(compared.country)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.liNumber.equals(compared.liNumber)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        
    }
```

Comment: Because at that point (the last statement), you could just return the condition of the if statement.

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 To be precise: The _inverted_ condition.

Comment: It is redundant, but I think clearer this way, since all comparisons follow the same code format, you don't have to wonder why one is different.

Comment: @John Bayko Yeah. I ignore it as well. You can disable that hint in preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you can simplify it using the return statement.

Example:

`return this.liNumber.equals(compared.liNumber);`

Comment: What about just `return this.liNumber.equals(compared.liNumber)`?

Comment: Oh, you're right; sorry my bad! I changed it now. Thank you Gerold.

Comment: Well, still bad: a "`!`" and a "`)`" too much.

Comment: Right, my bad, I rushed this.

Comment: Ok I understand. I got this from a yt tutorial. I think the way they showed it is more readable/maintainable?